# Squeezing a list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list in the form of

```
['RGT = (HDG, QJV)', 'QDM = (GPB, SXG)', 'DJN = (TQD, BQN)', 'QGG = (GGS, PTC)'..]
```

How can I turn it into a dictionary similar to the (not functioning) expression:

```
gamedict = {x[0]:x[1] for x.split('=') in (x for x in game)}
```

I know how to solve the problem with .split() in multiple lines.
I was just wondering if there is a sleaker option to improve my programming. Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected or desired output?

Comment: You should add the spaces in your x.split(' = ')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dict` constructor takes a sequence of key-value pairs, so you can construct the desired dict by splitting each string in the list by `' = '`:

```
dict(s.split(' = ', 1) for s in game)
```

This returns:

```
{'RGT': '(HDG, QJV)', 'QDM': '(GPB, SXG)', 'DJN': '(TQD, BQN)', 'QGG': '(GGS, PTC)'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess at the required output...

```
myList = ['RGT = (HDG, QJV)', 'QDM = (GPB, SXG)', 'DJN = (TQD, BQN)', 'QGG = (GGS, PTC)']
myDict = dict()

for s in myList:
    k, v = map(str.strip, s.split("="))
    myDict[k] = tuple(map(str.strip, v[1:-1].split(",")))

print(myDict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'RGT': ('HDG', 'QJV'), 'QDM': ('GPB', 'SXG'), 'DJN': ('TQD', 'BQN'), 'QGG': ('GGS', 'PTC')}
```